# HTTPs sites won't load CSS in any browser

Tags: windows, browser, https, css

Whenever I try to load a https website, the CSS stylesheet for the site won't load. I've looked around for answers, and apparently fixing the system time can resolve the problem but, as far as I can tell, my system time is correct.

Comment: What leads you to believe that your system time has any impact on the issue? is the sites certificate already expired or not yet active?

Comment: Are all sites affected or just some?

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: @ FrankThomas I've found other users with the same problem, and changing the system time has worked for them.
@James All sites. I can't even log into superuser, I'm using a guest account

Comment: @Chris: What kind of internet connection do you have and are there other devices on the same network that are working fine?

Comment: @Chris: If you are using Firefox, try pressing **Ctrl + Shift + K**. On Chrome the equivalent is **Ctrl + Shift + J**. This will show the browser's console window. Do you see any errors when you try to load a page over https? If so, please post the output here.

Comment: make sure your Year is right. I had a simillar issue with ALL ssl pages on a clients laptop. their clock was off by exactly one year, so when I first glanced at it, it seemed fine. are you able to do an internet time synch?

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the CSS files including HTTPS and offering them on the same domain?

For debugging you can use [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/firebug/). In the "Net" tab, you can see every request, including the webserver's response.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem - some sites wont load css. Example facebook. Facebook uses https protocol. I done fresh install of Win XP on PC from 2004 year, installed firefox and safari and both had same issue - no css for https sites. On other side some sites (for control) do load css and show correct graphics (like intel.com and other http sites).
I did not realize shortly that MB battery was empty and time was reset on default MB time.

When I come to this post I updated clock and css was loaded and https sites have original theme.
So .. it is correct that clock time have influence on loading css for https sites.